# How to use redis WATCH in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

### Background

I have an atomic operation and I need to use a lock to prevent other clients from reading an unstable value.

- **Platform**:  Node 10.1.0
- **Library**: [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

### Solution

According to the official documentation, the solution for this is to use `WATCH` together with `MULTI`:

- https://redis.io/topics/transactions
- https://redis.io/commands/watch

### Problem

Now, the usage of `MULTI` is documented and I have a general idea on how I can use it.

```
var redis = require( "redis" );
var bluebird = require( "bluebird" );
var client = redis.createClient();
var multi = client.multi();

multi.hsetAsync( "test", "array", "[1, 2]" );
multi.hgetAsync( "test", "array" );
multi.execAsync( ).then( console.log ); // [ 0, "[1, 2]" ]
```

I understand that this is the correct implementation of multi. First **i need** to create a client, and then I create a multi query.

I understand that `multi` and `client` share the same interface, but it is also not clear what benefits ( if any ) I have from using `hgetAsync` instead of `hget` in a `multi` query, since I assume that all that multi does is adding said requests to a queue synchronously ( therefore I shouldn't need the Async vartiant ).

Upon calling `multi.execAsync( )` the execution of the query will happen **atomically**.

But I don't get how `WATCH` is supposed to enter here. I couldn't find any reference to it in the documentation, not anything regarding the optimist lock system that REDIS has.

### Questions

So I have the following questions:

1. Is `WATCH` supported with `MULTI` ?
2. If so, can you share a code snippet ?
3. Does it make sense in this example to use `multi.hgetAsync( "test", "array" );` instead of `multi.hget( "test", "array" );` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Asnwer

There is no documentation regarding the usage of WATCH in node-redis. I did however found an extremely useful set of tips in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Redis_Tips

In sum, WATCH should be used like the following:

```
var redis  = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient({ ... });

client.watch("foo", function( err ){
    if(err) throw err;

    client.get("foo", function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;

        // Process result
        // Heavy and time consuming operation here

        client.multi()
            .set("foo", "some heavy computation")
            .exec(function(err, results) {

                /**
                 * If err is null, it means Redis successfully attempted 
                 * the operation.
                 */ 
                if(err) throw err;

                /**
                 * If results === null, it means that a concurrent client
                 * changed the key while we were processing it and thus 
                 * the execution of the MULTI command was not performed.
                 * 
                 * NOTICE: Failing an execution of MULTI is not considered
                 * an error. So you will have err === null and results === null
                 */

            });
    });
});
```

So, to answer my questions:

1. Yes, although `watch` is called on the `RedisClient` prototype and not on the `Multi` prototype.
2. Code snippet provided above.
3. Because each method from an object that has a `Multi` prototype returns the object itself, using the `Async` versions of the methods brings no benefit whatsoever, except for `execAsync` which allows you to execute the multi queries and deal with the response in a Promise instead of a callback.

### Important Notes

Another really important thing is that `watch` works for KEYS only, **not for hashes**. So in my case, you cannot watch the field `array` of the hash `test`. You can watch the entire `test` set, but not a specific field.

So, because in my code I actually want to watch a field on a hash. This is not possible. I must instead use a key naming system that will allow that instead:

```
var redis = require( "redis" );
var bluebird = require( "bluebird" );
var client = redis.createClient();
var multi = client.multi();

client.watchAsync( "test_array" )
    then( ( ) =>
        multi.set( "test_array", "[1, 2]" )
            .get( "test_array" )
            .execAsync( ) 
    )
    .then( console.log ); // [ 0, "[1, 2]" ]
```

The documentation for this is really sparse, but I hope this question helps someone in the future.

---

### Are you reading this [from the future](http://static.businessinsider.com/image/524473eb6bb3f7f64d4a8db7-750.jpg)?

If you are reading this from the future, you can now enjoy my personal contribution to the `node_redis` project and check the updated documentation:

- https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#optimistic-locks

Comment: Is it possibile to have a race condition using the same redis client?
I'm thinking about running the same MULTI with [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) for example.

Comment: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/isolated-execution.md#transactions  -- A new doc on node Redis explains this use case very well